# DEVEXPRESS - xtrareport - page break

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a datatable with more than 300 rows. 
I want each page to present only 10 rows in it.
I want to force the xtrareport to break after 10 rows.

Any idea on how this is done ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force a page break on certain conditions. [This page](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q240395.aspx) has an example at the bottom.

> Hi Cary,
>
> To accomplish this task you can either add a GroupFooter band and set the GroupFooter.PageBreak to AfterBand. **or put a XRPageBreak control, handle the Detail.BeforePrint and adjust the visibility of the XRPageBreak as you need.**
>   To get processing row you need to use the XtraReport.GetCurrentRow() method.
>   Please try this solution, and let us know the results.
>
> Thanks,
>   Andrew

Answer (score 5):

you need to create a Repport Merging.

- The first step is to create a main Repport.
- Then, create a second Repport every 10 rows.
- And, add this second Repport in the main Repport.

here is an example :

```
private void printInvoicesButton_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int[] selection = this.ordersGridView.GetSelectedRows();
        XtraReport reportMerge = new XtraReport();
        reportMerge.CreateDocument();

        IList<XtraReport> reportList = new List<XtraReport>();

        // Create a report.
        //invoiceReport report = new invoiceReport();

        for (int j = 0; j < selection.Length; j++)
        {


            XtraReport report = new XtraReport();
            string filePath = @"Reports/invoiceReport1.repx";
            report.LoadLayout(filePath);


            InvoiceData invoice = new InvoiceData();

            for (int i = 0; i < DataRepository.Orders.Orders.Count; i++)
            {
                if (
                    ordersGridView.GetRowCellValue(selection[j], "InvoiceCode").Equals(
                        DataRepository.Orders.Orders[i].InvoiceCode))
                {
                    BindingSource dataSource = new BindingSource();

                    invoice = InvoiceData.AdaptFrom(DataRepository.Orders.Orders[i], DataRepository.Orders,
                                                    DataRepository.Products.Products,
                                                    DataRepository.ProductOptionMaster,
                                                    DataRepository.ProductOptionDataSet,
                                                    DataRepository.CustomerShippingAddresses,
                                                    DataRepository.Customers.UserMaster,
                                                    DataRepository.AttributesData.Product_Attributes);

                    dataSource.Add(invoice);

                    report.DataSource = dataSource;
                    //report.ShowPreview();
                    report.CreateDocument();

                }
            }
            reportList.Add(report);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<reportList.Count;i++)
        {
            reportMerge.Pages.AddRange(reportList[i].Pages);
        }

        // Show the report's preview.
        reportMerge.ShowPreviewDialog();            

    }
```